# How do I use a variable from another method? (cannot find symbol - variable evenNum)

Tags: java

I am making a code that only prints the even numbers of an array. But I am having a problem sending `evenNum` variable from `countEm` to `getAllEvens`.

```
private static int countEm(int[] array)
    {
        int evenNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                evenNum++;
            }
        }
        return evenNum;
    }

    public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array)
    {      
        int[] evens = new int [evenNum];
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]%2==0)
            {
                evens[c] = array[i];
                c++;
            }
        }
        return evens;   
    }
```

How do I use a variable from another method?

Comment: This is a scope problem. `getAllEvens` has no way of accessing `evenNum`.

Comment: `int[] evens = new int[countEm(array)]`, most likely

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In that way, **gettAllEvents** will never get acces to evenNum.

You should declare it outside the function **countEm**